# What does 'on' followed after 'call' mean in each sentence?

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-usage, prepositions

In each sentence a bundle of 'call' and 'on' has different meaning. What does 'on' followed after 'call' mean in each sentence? Why does 'to' or 'for' not use instead of 'on'?

> 1. The Commissioner-General plans to call up on the Secretary-General of
>      OIC as soon as arrangements can be made.
> 2. We call on the Security Council to have them arrested and disarmed.
> 3. The Chairman: I call on the observer of Switzerland.
> 4. Eritrea renews this call on this occasion.

Comment: I think the first one is a typo, it should have been "call upon". As the other answers have pointed out, "call up on" is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **[call on](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/call-on)** (phrasal verb):
>
> 1. officially ask someone to do something
> 2. ask a student a question
> 3. decide to use something
> 4. produce a quality
> 5. ask someone to prove statement
> 6. visit someone for short time

Clearly this is a multi-purpose expression, as each of your examples has a slightly different meaning:

1. Probably "visit someone for a short time", or possibly "ask someone to do something".  Note it should be either "call up" or "call on", but not "call up on".  That's unnecessarily mixing the expressions.
2. A variation on "ask someone to prove statement", meaning "ask someone to take a certain action"
3. "Officially ask someone to do something", in this case, "to give a speech"
4. This one is difficult to understand without more context, but my best guess is that it's a finance term used in the stock market:

   > **Call options** are an agreement that give the option buyer the right, but not the obligation, to buy a stock, bond, commodity or other instrument at a specified price within a specific time period.

   This example is not actually the phrasal verb, but rather simply "call" as a noun, followed by the adverb phrase "on this occasion".  The company has decided to "renew" the "call" meaning that they are extending the specified time period.

Comment: So if 'call on' is a phrasal verb then verb particle 'on'  with 'call' has nothing to do with meanings of preposion 'on'? I say it because it is very difficult to remember all phrasal verb meanings without association with the same preposition.

Comment: @Vitaly  Consider "on" also means "activate" as in *turn on* vs. *turn off*.  This is only marginally related to using "on" as a preposition of location.  Most English prepositions serve many different roles depending on the context.  To "call on" someone (meaning "visit') is related to the idea of showing up *on* their doorstep.  Meanwhile "call on" a student (meaning "ask them a question") is akin to the idea of picking them by tapping them *on* the shoulder

Comment: @Vitaly But all of these are just logical conjecture, and I wouldn't worry about it too much.   Most of the time you can get the intended meaning from the context -- as long as you are familiar with the rest of the vocabulary, of course.  For example. you wouldn't know about a "call option" unless you read stuff related to the stock market.

Comment: Andrew, your logical conjectures are something!  It is very usefull for certain groups non native speakers.